# Styling individual list items using inline style?

Tags: css, html

I'm completely new to HTML and CSS, so please bear with me.

I want to change the color of an individual list item in an ordered list, but I don't want the list number to change style. I also need to do this within the one html-document -- no separate CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title> Test-page </title>
</head>

<body>
<h1> An html-file </h1>


<ol>
<li> Item 1 </li>
<li style="color:blue"> Item 2 </li>
<li> Item 3 </li>
</ol>


</body>
</html>
```

The only thing I can think of to solve this using inline styling, is:

```
<ol>
<li> Item 1 </li>
<li><p style="color:blue"> Item 2 </li>
<li> Item 3 </li>
</ol>
```

But the list items will appear to be separate paragraphs.
I don't want to use the font-tag, and I want to use HTML5. I want it to be as short as possible, in one file, therefore inline styling.

Comment: Use `span` instead of `p`

Comment: Also, don't forget to close your `span` tag like you did for the `p` tag. Unforeseen consequences may arise.

Comment: Embarrassing. I swear I've been searching w3schools for hours, obviously looking in the wrong place. Thanks Itay.

Comment: w3schools *is* a wrong place, see http://w3fools.com

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I had no idea. Thanks for enlightening me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any CSS rule that you set on a `li` element also applies to the list item marker (bullet, number). This is inconvenient, and CSS still lacks any way to style the list marker separately.

So your approach of using something like `<li><p style="color:blue"> Item 2 </li>` is the workaround you need to use, but when selecting the added inner element, you need to consider the consequences. A `p` element has default top and bottom margin, so using it, you would need to remove them here:

```
<li><p style="color:blue; margin:0"> Item 2 </li>
```

A simpler way is to use `div` instead of `p`, since `div` is a semantically emply block-level container element, which causes no change in default rendering except that its content starts on a fresh line and the content after it starts on a fresh line, which happens here anyway due to the list markup. So:

```
<li><div style="color:blue"> Item 2</div></li>
```

Instead of `div`, you can use `span`, if there is only inline (phrase-level) content. But `div` is more flexible, as it allows elements like inner lists, tables, etc.

Answer (score 0):

LIke this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LD9KM/)**

**css**

```
ol li span{
color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `span` tag in place of `p`. And don't forget to close the tags properly:

```
<ol>
    <li><span style="color:blue">Item 2</span></li>
</ol>
```

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><span style="color:blue">Item</span>2</li>
```